# GetSystemTimeAdjustment in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

A problem I was having was how to check the GetSystemTimeAdjustment value in PowerShell so I could determine the minimum time to wait for threads to finish in some background automation before checking to see if they should be collected as Jobs in PowerShell 5 (I can't use 7 yet for business reasons and continuity of support)

How can we find the default minimum thread slice time for the version of Windows we are on?

Comment: There are a lot of blogs that cover this information, but I wanted to put up a simple code block to save (myself, I'm sure) people time figuring it out when searching for the specific terms. Hopefully it helps (me, in the future)

Answer (score 0):

```
Add-Type -Assembly "System.ServiceModel.Internals"
$assembly = [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where({ $_.GetName().Name -match 'System.ServiceModel.Internals' })
$timer = $assembly.GetTypes().Where({ $_.Name -eq 'IOThreadTimer' })
$timerValue = $timer.GetProperty("SystemTimeResolutionTicks").GetValue($null)
```

Note, this is the value you get in an interactive shell, so you are not guaranteed to have every process get the same time slice, but it is from the system via

```
// System.Runtime.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods
public static extern uint GetSystemTimeAdjustment(out int adjustment, out uint increment, out uint adjustmentDisabled);
```

Additionally, your actual command may take less than 15ms to return, this is for determining the system increment of time that the thread scheduler will wait before it attempts to switch tasks.